# Is the number of atoms in a finite lattice always less than or equal to the length of the lattice?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

My attempt: Let $\{v_1, v_2,...,v_m\}$ is the set of atoms in a finite lattice L. Now the chain

$0<v_1 \lt (v_1 \lor v_2) \lt (v_1 \lor v_2 \lor v_3) \lt...\lt (v_1\lor v_2 \lor ...\lor v_m) \leq I$

is in L. And the length of this chain is less than or equal to m.

Comment: Those inequalities don't necessarily hold. For example, take the lattice which has the atoms $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ and one element below, $0$, and one element above, $1$. Its length is $2$. The problem is that $$v_1\vee v_2=v_1\vee v_2\vee v_3 = v_1\vee v_2\vee\cdots\vee v_n.$$

Comment: Can you please suggest some books for the deep study of atomic lattices?

Comment: I suppose that *Introduction to Lattices and Order* by Davey and Priestley, and *General Lattice Theory* by George Grätzer are still reference books (they were, in my time). I also suppose there are now others that I don't know. Meanwhile, looking at your post again, I came to the conclusion that your conjecture is true for *distributive lattices*. Perhaps you forgot that assumption?

Comment: I know the result is true for distributed lattice, but I was wondering whether it is true for complemented lattice.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.